# How to make Angular respect optional binding with inline objects?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have an attribute on my directive which is marked as optional, using a `?`:

```
scope: {
    a:'=?'
},
```

This should mean that that you can pass in one-way bound things if you choose to.  Such as `a="foo()"`.

However, when I try to pass in an inline object, `a="{x: 5}"`, it fails with an error:

> Error: [$compile:nonassign] Expression '{ x: 5 }' in attribute 'a' used with directive 'dir' is non-assignable!

It appears to ignore my `?` in this case.  **Is there some way to make it respect the `?` or suppress the error?**

Here is an example of it working with a function but failing for an object:

http://jsbin.com/fapodigiza/edit?html,js,console,output

Answer (score 1):

It is because you are mistaken =? is for optional two-way biding, it does not make your biding one-way. To make optional one-way biding use this:

```js
angular
.module('app', [])
.directive('dir', function(){
    return {
        template: 
     '<div>a: {{a}} <br />b: {{b}} <br />c: {{c}}</div>',
        scope: {
            a:'<?',
            b:'<?',
            c:'<?'
        },
        link: function(scope){
            scope.$root.func = function() {
              return 'rootFunc';
            }
          
            scope.a=1;
            scope.b=1;
            scope.c=1;
        }
    };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app">
  <dir
    a="{ x: 5 }"
    b="func()"
  ></dir>
</div>
```

Comment: Optional two-way binding is indeed what I want.  What do you think is the difference between "optional two-way" and "one-way"?  Don't they end up being the same thing?

Comment: @BuhBuh this article explains it pretty well https://toddmotto.com/one-way-data-binding-in-angular-1-5/ and you can't do what you wan't with two-way data binding, because literal values are not assignable, so error would be thrown if you try this, just like in your case. With one-way problem is non-existing cos original value is never change, although you can add/remove properties on reference, you just cannot change it.

Comment: Why does it not error when I attempt a two way bind to foo()? Surely foo() is unasignable too.

Comment: @BuhBuh It is and this is where things get interesting, because, when we do it like this: http://jsbin.com/wokatobipa/4/edit?html,js,console,output error is thrown as it should be, but if you create func inside directive then scope.b is undefined, so it acts as if it was never passed to directive, so it assignable then. I think that passing values to scope in directive is done before linking function is called, so when there is no func defined when you are using this directive first time, so it acts as b was never used, so you can assign something to b.